# Want to iterate through half of mongoDB and iterate through the rest of the half with another query

Tags: java, mongodb, jongo

I'm getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCursorNotFoundException:
>   Query failed with error code -5 and error message 'Cursor 304054517192
>   not found on server mongodb2:27017' on server mongodb2:27017  at
>   com.mongodb.operation.QueryHelper.translateCommandException(QueryHelper.java:27)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.getMore(QueryBatchCursor.java:215)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.hasNext(QueryBatchCursor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.MongoBatchCursorAdapter.hasNext(MongoBatchCursorAdapter.java:46)
>     at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:155)  at
>   org.jongo.MongoCursor.hasNext(MongoCursor.java:38)    at
>   com.abc.Generator.Generate(Generator.java:162)    at
>   com.abc.main.main(main.java:72)

which I assume is because the query ran for too long.
So I'm planning to query mongo using `find()` and iterate through half of the collections.
Then I want to use another `find()` query and iterate through the remaining half of the collections.

Could you help with how to directly place the cursor at the half'th position of the collection? [The documentation does not seem to provide](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html) any functions for it.

I'm basically just using a `find()` and iterating thru a collection with 100000 records, while connected to a server via `ssh`.

```
MongoCollection history = jongo.getCollection("historyCollection");
MongoCursor<MyClass> allHistories = history.find().as(MyClass.class);

  //---Iterate thru all histories
  while (allHistories.hasNext()) {
  MyClass oneHistory = allHistories.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by having the Mongo collections ordered by ObjectId's that were timestamps. This way, I was able to use the greater than operator to find objectIDs and split the iterations.

```
private MongoCursor<PersonDBO> ReadFewProfilesFromDB(final String objectIdAfterWhichToSearchFrom, final Integer FIND_LIMIT) {

    MongoCursor<PersonDBO> aBatchOfProfiles = null;

    try {
        if (objectIdAfterWhichToSearchFrom.equals(START_OBJECTID_OF_MONGO_BATCHES)) {
            aBatchOfProfiles = personProfile.find().limit(FIND_LIMIT).as(PersonDBO.class);
        } else {
            aBatchOfProfiles = personProfile.find("{_id: {$gt: #}}", new ObjectId(objectIdAfterWhichToSearchFrom)).limit(FIND_LIMIT).as(PersonDBO.class);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {logger.error("Problem while trying to find {} personProfiles, starting from objectID {}. {}, {}", FIND_LIMIT, objectIdAfterWhichToSearchFrom, e.getMessage(), e.getCause());}

    if (aBatchOfProfiles == null) {
        logger.error("profiles collection is null. Nothing more to iterate OR there was an exception when finding profiles. If exception, there would be an error printed above.");
        return null;
    }         

    return aBatchOfProfiles;
}
```